# Filter vs -ms-filter

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Does IE8 support filter. Are there any exceptions or i have to use both in the below code

```
/* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#7795c6', endColorstr='#61b145'); 
/* For Internet Explorer 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#7795c6', endColorstr='#61b145')";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes IE8 supports `filter`. This:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#7795c6', endColorstr='#61b145');
```

…works in IE8 as well.

Comment: +1. It’s a common misconception that both `-ms-filter` and `filter` are needed if there’s already a `filter` property available.

Comment: "This topic documents a feature of Visual Filters and Transitions, which is deprecated as of Windows Internet Explorer 9." from Introduction to Filters and Transitions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx)